# Problems with select on sailsJs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i have problems with sailsJs
i want to select all of  with count of messages , group + count of messages which belong to the current group,
my code like this

```
Group.find().exec(function (err, groups) {
    if (err)
        return next(err);
    _.each(groups, function (grouper) {
        Messages.find({
            groupId : grouper.id,
        }).exec(function (err, somethingfunctions) {
            console.log(groups),
            console.log(somethingfunctions.length),
        });
    });
});
```

i want somethink like this

name of group + count of messages which belong to the current group;
for example

```
webdevelopment - 34 messages
```

i can't understand how to do this with sailsJs

Comment: I think the answer below addresses one aspect of the problem (counting the Messages). There remains one: doing multiple `Messages.find()` or `Messages.count()` inside the `_.each()` loop implies that you must somehow get the results of *all* the queries' callbacks. So you must have some synchronization mechanism, so that you get all the callbacks results before sending your response. I will try to find an example of how you can achieve this, with a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `count` method provided for the `models` inside `_.each(groups, function (grouper)`, like so:

```
Messages
.count({groupId : grouper.id})
.exec(function (err, found) {
  if(!err) console.log(grouper.name + ' - ' + found + ' messages.');
});
```

But, there's a better way to do this. You are running a query once for each groupId (NOT GOOD!), when you can get the result in ONE `Native` Query !

```
Messages.native(function (err, MessageCollecion){
  MessageCollecion.aggregate(
    { $group: 
      { _id: '$groupId', total_messages: { $sum: 1 } } 
    },
    function (err, res) {
      if (!err) console.log(res);
    });
});
```

This will give you `groupId` instead of `group name`. So you can query once for all groups, and then get the name from the id. Still, 2 `queries` are better then querying once for each `groupId`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
var async = require('async');  // npm install async before running Sails

Group.find().exec(function (err, groups) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    // Create a group of async tasks
    var tasks = {};

    _.each(groups, function (group) {
        // For each group, create a task. This task will execute Message.count()
        // for the specified group. Once done, the task will pass on its results
        // to a callback. The task is NOT started right away.
        tasks[group.name] = (function(_groupId) {
            return function(callback) {
                Messages.count({groupId: _groupId}).exec(callback);
            }
        })(group.id);
    });

    // Now start the tasks, executing them in sequence, one after the other.
    // At the end, the callback passed to async.series() gets an aggregate
    // of all the individual tasks' results in its results parameter.
    async.series( tasks, function( err, results ) {
        // send the results as JSON.
        res.json( results );
    } );

});
```

Hope this helps. Another way to do it (and way simpler) would be to define associations between your models. E.g. in `api/models/Group.js`:

```
// Group model
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        ...,
        messages : { collection: 'Messages', via: 'group' },
        ...
    }
};
```

And in `api/models/Messages.js`:

```
// Messages model
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        ...,
        group : { model: 'Group' },
        ...
    }
};
```

Then you could use a query to get the groups and their associated messages as populated values,  see [Waterline reference - populated values](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/populated-values):

```
Group.find()
.populate('messages')  // a "collection" association
.exec(function (err, groups){
    // Now each group in groups has a populated messages attribute
});
```